# Filter does not return the correct result

Tags: javascript

I have this array and I created this function that return me the filtered array:

```js
const result = [{
      key: 'A',
      title: 'titleA',
      data: [{
          name: 'miael',
          id: 'id4',
        },
        {
          name: 'top',
          id: 'id2',
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      key: 'B',
      title: 'titleB',
      data: [{
          name: 'mich1',
          id: 'id12',
        },
        {
          name: 'tomato',
          id: 'id123',
        }
      ]
    },

  ]

  const doSearch = (data) => result.filter(entry =>
    entry.data.some(item =>
      item.name
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(data.toString().toLowerCase().trim()),
    ),
  );

console.log(doSearch('mich'));
```

This works, but it also returns results that do not contain the searched word 'mic'

if I search for mic, I expect this result:

```
[{
  key: 'B',
  title: 'titleB',
  data: [{
      name: 'mich1',
      id: 'id12',
    },
 
  ]
}],
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @SebastianSimon mic sorry, return me entire array of object that contain Mic, but i want only Mic in the data array

Comment: @jabaa so? where is the problem?

Comment: Okay, now it’s somewhat clear. I’d recommend to `map` over the result, mapping each object to a new object, where the `key` and `title` properties are copied, but the `data` property is set to the result of _another_ `filter`.

Comment: You're filtering the array `result`. It contains two elements. First element has key `A` and second element has key `B`. The element with key `A` doesn't contain `mic` and is discarded. The second element contains `mic`. You have to also filter `entry.data`, to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of changes should make this work the way you wish.

- Turning `doSearch` into a function.
- Adding a `searchFor` parameter to the `doSearch()` function and passing to the .includes() call.
- Using `Array.reduce()` to create the output array. Items are only added if they include the searchFor value.

```js
const input = [{ key: 'A', title: 'titleA', data: [{ name: 'miael', id: 'id4', }, { name: 'top', id: 'id2', } ] },  { key: 'B', title: 'titleB', data: [{ name: 'mich1', id: 'id12', }, { name: 'tomato', id: 'id123', } ] },  ] 

const doSearch = (searchFor, arr) => arr.reduce((acc, { key, title, data }) => {
    const filteredData = data.filter(({ name }) => { 
        return name.toLowerCase().includes(searchFor.toLowerCase())
    });
    if (filteredData.length > 0) { 
        acc.push({ key, title, data: filteredData });
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(doSearch('mic', input ));
```

Comment: good code but i use spread operator not push :P

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your current logic and add a `map` with the same filter for `entry.data`:

```js
const result = [{
    key: 'A',
    title: 'titleA',
    data: [{
        name: 'miael',
        id: 'id4',
      },
      {
        name: 'top',
        id: 'id2',
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    key: 'B',
    title: 'titleB',
    data: [{
        name: 'mich1',
        id: 'id12',
      },
      {
        name: 'tomato',
        id: 'id123',
      }
    ]
  },

]

function nameFilter(item, data) {
  return item.name
    .toString()
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(data.toString().toLowerCase().trim())
}

const doSearch = (data) => result.filter(entry =>
  entry.data.some(item =>
    nameFilter(item, data)
  ),
).map(entry => ({
  ...entry,
  data: entry.data.filter(item => nameFilter(item, data))
}));

console.log(doSearch('mich'));
```